# link from top-level menu to user role in profile page

Tags: php, wordpress

I'd like to add a WordPress custom link to the admin top level menu. The link should lead to a specific role (Repair Customer) from the users profile page.
I tried this in my child theme's functions.php:

```
add_menu_page( 'Repair Customers', 'Repair Customers', 'manage_plugins', 'users.php?role=repair-customer', '', 'dashicons-groups', 71 );
```

This does not create a menu item. Any suggestions to solve his?

Comment: I check it your code working fine. issue in manage_plugins. Create properly role then check it. add role  add_role( 'customers', 'customers', array( 'read' => true, 'level_0' => true,''manage_plugins'=> true ) );

Comment: Create role as per your desired requirment

Comment: Reallly i have so much disappointed when you people give us no response

Comment: @Sajid: this particular role is already created. I just want an easy way to get a list of users with this role from the top level menu. B.t.w. if I put user.php without the parameter ?role=repair-customer, then the menu item is created (the same as the regular "Users" menu-item).